# How to set onClick event per each divisions in map?

Tags: android

Let say I have this kind of image in my android imageView. Now each state consists of it's own region.

How to set `onClick` event based on each state in map? Example for my expected output would be  if I click region `Alor Setar` then `Log.i("map","Alor Setar")` Is it any better ideas for this requirement?

Help me, thanks!

[image]

---

I have tried:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

    int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);
    int red = Color.red(pixel);
    int blue = Color.blue(pixel);
    int green = Color.green(pixel);
    Log.d(TAG,"Color = "+red);
    Log.d(TAG,"Color = "+green);
    Log.d(TAG,"Color = "+blue);
    return false;
}
```

But the errors:

```
05-26 10:45:10.463 3289-3289/com.example.flow.detail.master.masterdetailflow E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
05-26 10:45:10.473 3289-3289/com.example.flow.detail.master.masterdetailflow E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: y must be < bitmap.height()
                                                                                                     at android.graphics.Bitmap.checkPixelAccess(Bitmap.java:1403)
                                                                                                     at android.graphics.Bitmap.getPixel(Bitmap.java:1352)
                                                                                                     at com.example.flow.detail.master.masterdetailflow.JsonActivity.onTouchEvent(JsonActivity.java:103)
                                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2837)
                                                                                                     at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:71)
                                                                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2414)
                                                                                                     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9543)
                                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4248)
                                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4114)
                                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
                                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
                                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3805)
                                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
                                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3862)
                                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
                                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
                                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
                                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5951)
                                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5925)
                                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5875)
                                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6054)
                                                                                                     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
                                                                                                     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                                                                                                     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
                                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5468)
                                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
05-26 10:45:10.474 3289-3289/com.example.flow.detail.master.masterdetailflow E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                               Process: com.example.flow.detail.master.masterdetailflow, PID: 3289
                                                                                               java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: y must be < bitmap.height()
                                                                                                   at android.graphics.Bitmap.checkPixelAccess(Bitmap.java:1403)
                                                                                                   at android.graphics.Bitmap.getPixel(Bitmap.java:1352)
                                                                                                   at com.example.flow.detail.master.masterdetailflow.JsonActivity.onTouchEvent(JsonActivity.java:103)
                                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2837)
                                                                                                   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:71)
                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2414)
                                                                                                   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9543)
                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4248)
                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4114)
                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3805)
                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3862)
                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5951)
                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5925)
                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5875)
                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6054)
                                                                                                   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
                                                                                                   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                                                                                                   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
                                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5468)
                                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can get the RGB of color.
//根据坐标获取
ImageView imageView = ((ImageView)v);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);
//获取颜色
int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);
```

Comment: Can you explain?I'm new bie here.

Comment: How to define in `bitmap.getPixel(x,y);`? since `x` and `y` not define yet.

Comment: Can you open this?

Comment: Oh no, I do not understand chinese Language

Comment: You need setOnTouchListener to this imageview

Comment: iv_image.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {@Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event).....

Comment: I find the Demo in Github.https://github.com/Jackwaiting/RGB-to-get-the-Android-value-of-the-picture

Comment: Ok thanks. So it's all about detect the colour code based on position.

Comment: I tried your codes, the colour return does not correct. For example, if i clicked region `Kelantan` the rgb return `red=0, green=135, blue=53`. It should be return blue but in my case it return green.